# How can I use google font with preload in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

I am using NextJS with Tailwind CSS. I have included link in my `_document.js` file.
I am using link like this.

```html
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono:wght@700&display=swap" as="style" />
```

How can I use preload with google font?

Comment: What's not working exactly?

Comment: Do you want to preload the font files or just the font CSS? If just the CSS, then you don't need to do that, Next.js directly injects CSS from the link during build. See: [Web Font Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization)